# Django integrity error on parallel requests

Tags: django, postgresql, race-condition

I have:

```
IntegrityError
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "user_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(3220037) already exists.
```

This happens in this part of the code

```
            user = User()
            user.save()
```

Model is pretty simple, 3 fields. So it happens when there are lot's of parallel requests to my endpoint.

I thought Django deals with **race condition** under the hood in such an easy operation. Database is Postgres, default transaction isolation is **read commited**.

Maybe smth changed with newer Django versions? Do I have to handle **race condition** by myself in code?

Answer (score 0):

Use transaction atomic on your model queryset.

Solution #1:

```
@transaction.atomic
def create_user():
    user = User()
    user.save()
```

Solution #2:

```
 with transaction.atomic():
   user = User()
   user.save()
```

and use select_update_or_create

Comment: As I know from, `@transaction.atomic` does rollback if an `IntegrityError` happens.

But it will not prevent Error from happening.